# CuDNNLSTM slower than LSTM in TensorFlow2

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm, tensorflow2.0

I read on multiple sources that using CuDNNLSTM instead of LSTM Layer on a GPU machine speeds up things. But it does not seem to be the case for me. I conducted a simple experiment as described below-

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

num_items, emb_dim, lstm_dim = int(1e6), 64, 1024

model_1 = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_items, emb_dim),
                            tf.keras.layers.LSTM(lstm_dim)
                            ])

model_2 = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_items, emb_dim),
                            tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(lstm_dim)
                            ])

def data_gen(iterations=5000):
  i=0
  while i<iterations:
    inp = tf.random.uniform(shape=[64, 20], minval=0, maxval=100000, dtype=tf.int64)
    yield inp
    i+=1

gen = data_gen()
tick=time.time()
for inp in gen:
    lstm = model_1(inp)
print(f'time taken by LSTM based model: {time.time()-tick} sec')

gen = data_gen()
tick=time.time()
for inp in gen:
    lstm = model_2(inp)
print(f'time taken by CuDNNLSTM based model: {time.time()-tick} sec')
```

And I got the following results-

```
time taken by LSTM based model: 60.24342346191406 sec
time taken by CuDNNLSTM based model: 65.31983590126038 sec
```

Any idea what might be the reason behind it?

Comment: The LSTM layers in TF2 use CuDNN by default, if you retain most default parameter values. Use the LSTM layers of the current API not the backwards compatibility API.

Comment: First of all, thanks for replying @SusmitAgrawal! 
So you are saying that I should use LSTM layer only. Was CuDNNLSTM helpful in tf1?

Comment: That's correct. The TF1.X LSTM layers didn't use CuDNN. TF2.X LSTM layers use it.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal I could not guess it because it is not mentioned on the official site https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/keras/layers/CuDNNLSTM

Anyway, thanks for clearing my doubt :)